# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden in asp.net visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012

I was editing my CSS code and every thing was OK for hours but just for once i saved the code and reloaded the web page  this error (HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden) appeared. 
i don't know what's wrong with it and why such problem appeared suddenly.
- I tried to use microsoft suggestion:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942062 but directory c:\windows\system32\inetsrv is empty (!) so inetmgr.exe could not be opened. - adding these to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

wasn't useful too.and setting the `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">` does not make any changes.I updated visual studio 2012 and it wasn't useful too.
(IIS 8.0 express  seems to be installed correctly , also visual studio 2010 is installed on my machine).
later I found out that if more than one vs2012 is opened this error could be displayed.

thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you accessing a file within your site via url or the web root?

Comment: yes APP_Data and and image folder and files within it and nothing else

Comment: Were you previously able to compile the solution and display the start page (when you hit F5), or is this your first attempt in doing so?

Comment: yes many times and it was OK

Comment: If you right click your web project and select properties and set the Start Action to blank or "/" then the browser will always load your start page. If you hit F5 and have the current page option selected in properties then the browser will request whatever page you currently have selected in your solutions.

Comment: The app pool that the application is using, what identity is it running under?

Comment: there is a MDF file in app_data that stores login information

Comment: @lrb would you please explain what difference can it possibly make? is it a source of my problem? thanks again.

Comment: If you are building an mvc app then loading the current page could bypass the bulk of code meant to load on entry. This would be more apparent if you are using forms authentication. The error you are getting is a "directory browsing not allowed" type of error. Maybe the route does not exist. If you do not set a start page then I would recommend you always run from the context of the solution. That way your configured start page will always load.

Comment: @lrb , I did it , but still I'm facing this error... from now on I would follow your recommendation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after updating my Visual studio i never faced such error , it seem there was a bug on my previous version of software , but this error also can appear when user is editing a class or web.config and start debugging the application . by the way if you have my problem re-install VS or just upgrade it , I hope it helps you and prevents wasting your time.